# Compute $\Pr(X+Y \le 5) $ if $X,Y \approx \mathcal{B}(10, \frac{1}{3})$

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y$ be independent random variable with binomial distribution (for $n=10$ and $p=\frac{1}{3}$). Compute $\Pr(X+Y \le 5)$.

Of course, I can consider all possibilities e.g.  $\Pr(X+Y \le 5) = \Pr(X=0,Y=0)+\Pr(X=0,Y=1) + \Pr(X=1,Y=1) + ... + \Pr(X=4,Y=5) + \Pr(X=5,Y=5)$ and now use independency but it is very long time way (I have $50$ elements).

I can notice that $$\Pr(X+Y \le 5) = \Pr(Y \le 5-X) = \sum_{i=0}^5 \Pr(Y \le 5-i|X=i)\Pr(X=i) = \\ \sum_{i=0}^5 \Pr(Y \le 5-i)\Pr(X=i)  $$

In this case I have maybe less elements to compute but the way to compute all of them is long.

Is it maybe faster way to gain $\Pr(X+Y \le 5)$ ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: a Binomial counts the number of successes on $n$ trials of a Bernoulli (0/1) variable; hence the sum of two iid Binomials counts [...] and so (perhaps?) it's itself a Binomial

Comment: If $X,Y$ are independent and $X  \approx \mathcal B(n,p)$ and $Y  \approx \mathcal B(m,p)$ then $X+Y  \approx \mathcal B(m+n,p)$. So now the task is quite easy. But I would prove this fact. Couly you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Think of a binomial distributed $X$ with parameters $n$ and
$p$ as $X=X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}$ where the $X_{i}$ are independent
and take values in $\left\{ 0,1\right\} $ with $P\{X_{i}=1\}=p$.